# Search Multiple Fields Same Parameter

Tags: search, merge

I'm building a search form with filters. This is one of the filters.
I would like to use the parameter "agent" and have it search a text field called "listingAgent" and "coListingAgent" to check for a match either place.  I tried the code below, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
    {% set getAgent = craft.request.getParam('agent') %}
    {% if getAgent %}
        {% set params = params|merge({ 'listingAgent':getAgent, 'coListingAgent':getAgent }) %}
    {% endif %}
```

additional info:
I noticed that setting the params twice (like below) is looking for a match in both fields. I am looking for a match in either field. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

```
{% set getAgent = craft.request.getParam('agent') %}
    {% if getAgent %}
        {% set params = params|merge({'listingAgent':getAgent}) %}
        {% set params = params|merge({'coListingAgent':getAgent}) %}
    {% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries(params).search() %}
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html

Comment: I did and I got the impression I could use "OR", I tried  {% set params = params|merge({'listingAgent':getAgent} OR {'coListingAgent':getAgent})and get the error back Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "OR" ("punctuation" expected with value ",").

Answer (score 1):

You have two different options. You can either use Crafts [search](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html) so your string would be `listingAgent:*searchterm* OR coListingAgent:*searchterm*` or `listingAgent:searchterm OR coListingAgent:searchterm` if it should be an exact search

```
{% set results = craft.entries()
    .search({
        query: 'listingAgent:*' ~ getAgent ~ '* OR  coListingAgent:*' ~ getAgent  ~ '*',
        subLeft: true,
        subRight: true
    })
    .all() 
%}
```

or you query correctly for the field values but I would prefer to do that in PHP instead of Twig

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since this is just one parameter of a more complex search, how could I put that into syntax in my params variable (from my original post)?

Comment: Why do you even want to do that. Twigs `|merge` function is so resource heavy I would suggest you not to use it too much. You can easily check if the parameter is set, if so attach it to the query

Comment: I guess overall I just don't understand the method you're describing. Sorry I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: `craft.entries` does not return an array of elements but an object of type `query` you can call all the functions you would like in the query in order to attach your criterias. You can do `{% set query = craft.entries.section('whatever') %}` and then append certain values `{% do query.search(getAgent) %}` and to fetch the entries `{% set entries = query.all() %}`

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Could you help me with the query syntax? I have query: 'listingAgent:* ~ address ~ '* OR  coListingAgent:*' ~ address  ~ '*', and I'm getting an error Unexpected character " ' ".

Comment: @triplethreat23 I had a syntax error in my code (missing one `'`) and you copied it